# How do I move 4 images from center to 4 corners using ObjectAnimator?

Tags: android, android-animation, animator

When I click on the button, 4 images placed in the center should move from center to 4 corners.

How it is possible by using `ObjectAnimator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the translationX and translationY property of the ObjectAnimator to achieve this.
You need to get the new position you want to move to. (endX,endY) It's better to use functions to arrive at this rather than hardcoding, to avoid making the animation look weird on different devices.
After that's done, Follow this...

```
ObjectAnimator transX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView,"x",startPos,endPos); 
ObjectAnimator transY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView,"y",startPos,endPos);  
AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
animSetXY.playTogether(transX, transY);
animSetXY.start();
```

You can personalise your animator by using `transX.setDuration()`, `transX.setRepeatCount()`, `transX.setRepeatMode()` etc.,

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how to get this  endposition? I tried to get the width and height of the screen, but that's not the right way to do that. Can you please help me ?

Comment: @AnuRoy Say `container` is the parent layout of your images, and say you'd want to move  your first image `imageOne` to the top left corner. Then, `container.getX()` and `container.getY()` gives you the start coordinates of your container. `...(imageOne, "x" , imageOne.getX() , container.getX())` and `...(imageOne, "y" , imageOne.getY() , container.getY())`. To get the other four coordinates of your container you add up `container.getMeasuredWidth/Height()`. I kept it short cuz it's a comment, hope you can solve your problem out of this.

Comment: Can you please mention all four corner coordinates? Little confused about it. Please help me.

Comment: I guess.. TL =>`(c.getX(),c.getY())` TR => `(c.getX()+c.getMeasuredWidth, c.getY)` BL => `(c.getX(), c.getY()+c.getMeasuredHeight())` BR=> `(c.getX()+getMeasuredWidth(), c.getY()+getMeasuredHeight())`. Please remember to subtract your image dimensions for the other three corners.

Comment: Can you please make it clear - "Substract your image dimensions for the other three corners."